# Issue in combining FindRoot and NIntegrate

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

The following gives compile warnings and returns unevaluated, any idea why?

```
obj2[a_] := 
 NIntegrate[(
   E^(1/2 (-x[1]^2 - x[2]^2))
     Log[Abs[1 - a (x[1]^2 + x[2]^2)]] x[
     1]^2)/(\[Pi] (x[1]^2 + x[2]^2)), {x[
     1], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {x[
     2], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] + Log[2]/2;
obj2[.915]   (* -0.00319086 + 5.42344*10^-18 I *)

FindRoot[obj2[a], {a, 0.92}]   (* compile errors + returns unevaluated *)
```

Also, I'm curious why the result of `NIntegrate` is complex, the only suspect part is `Log[Abs[x]]`, but it should be real for all x.

(it's the objective from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/586427/511))

Comment: Using `obj2[a_?NumericQ]` and forcing  `WorkingPrecision -> 15` with NIntegrate  works fine for me.  May be due to Log and Abs and the singularity at  `Abs[1 - 183/200 (x[1]^2 + x[2]^2)] == 0`  there is loss of workingPrecision below machinePrecision.

Answer (score 2):

The two problems seem to be related, or at least can be cured together:

```
obj2[a_?NumericQ] := 
  Chop[NIntegrate[(E^(1/2 (-x[1]^2 - x[2]^2)) Log[
         Abs[1 - a (x[1]^2 + x[2]^2)]] x[1]^2)/(\[Pi] (x[1]^2 + 
         x[2]^2)), {x[1], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {x[
       2], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] + Log[2]/2];
obj2[.915]  (* -0.00319086 *)
FindRoot[obj2[a], {a, 0.92}]  (* {a -> 0.918611} *)
```

The two modifications are:

- Using a test to sanitize the inputs of `obj2`.  Using the pattern `a_?NumericQ` inside a function definition means that the function will only be evaluated if `NumericQ` evaluates to `True` on an argument, and will be return unevaluated if it does not.  In particular, this prevents `FindRoot` from trying to take symbolic derivatives of `obj2` in its internal algorithms, which it will do by default.
- `Chop` removes "small" complex parts from numerical outputs.  Like you, I'm unsure why `NIntegrate` is returning a complex part for this integrand at all;  but it apparently causes `FindRoot` to invoke some kind of algorithm that does not converge.  Making sure that `obj2` only ever returns a real output makes `FindRoot` much happier.

Comment: OP: Please don't accept this answer immediately, as the Mathematica internals wizards on this forum might be able to provide a better insight into why all of this happened in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Use the settings by @Akku14, we can find two roots in `0<a<1`.

```
Clear[obj2]; 
obj2[a_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(E^(1/2 (-x[1]^2 - x[2]^2)) Log[
       Abs[1 - a (x[1]^2 + x[2]^2)]] x[1]^2)/(π (x[1]^2 + 
        x[2]^2)), {x[1], -∞, ∞}, {x[
     2], -∞, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 15] + 
  Log[2]/2;
FindRoot[obj2[a], {a, 0.2}]

FindRoot[obj2[a], {a, 0.8}]

ReImPlot[obj2[a], {a, 0, 1}]
```

> `{a -> 0.121312}`

> `{a -> 0.918611}`

[image]